# Firebase Functions/Firestore - Delete document doesn't actually delete it but only the content

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is the piece of code I am using to delete a user from the database. I understand that `delete()` is supposed to remove the document. But instead, it removes all the fields except `id`.

```
"use strict";

// Using Express
const express = require('express');

// Cloud Functions
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// Cloud Firestore
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

// Apps
const userApp = express();

userApp.get('/', async (request, response) => {
    const snapshot = await usersRef.get();
    let users = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let id = doc.id;
        let data = doc.data();
        users.push({ id, ...data });
    })
    response.status(200).send(users);
});

userApp.delete('/:id', async (request, response) => {
    await usersRef.doc(request.params.id).delete();
    response.status(200).send();
});
```

The logs are fine, I have a 200.

Am I doing something wrong?
or is the userId separate from the user in Firestore?

This is the JSON I have when I get all the users. Only the id is left.

```
[
    {
        "id": "R7bzt1OcmaDAGEwVxi4P",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "photoURL": "url.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "V8OOBHnrdnZPBafSziFxiEKKvvt2" <--- this one is the one I expect to not be here anymore when I used `doc().delete();`
    },
    {
        "id": "fcFG3AM31knPYfxQWzIR",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "photoURL": "url.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "wxDRxMExz8UXXA6bThjH",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "photoURL": "url.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing here and how it relates to the code.  It would be helpful if you explain in more detail what you're showing, and why it's not what you expect.  Also, on Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: If you're trying to show the contents of a document, a screenshot of the console might be more helpful.  If that JSON is the output of a program, we'd need to see that program and understand what you expected differently.

Comment: Is it better that way? It is pretty straightforward. I am using the cloud functions sdk to delete a user by using `.delete()` on the document. and instead of deleting the whole document, it deletes only its variables.

Comment: Now, what exactly are you doing to "get all the users"?  What code generates that output?  That seems like the problem here.  If the document is gone from the console, then the delete worked just fine.

Comment: I updated with the get users functions. I don't think this one is wrong.

Comment: In firebase console the user doesn't show up in the `users` collections. But when I get the users through the functions above, it returns the one I deleted without the content.

Comment: Ok, I didn't change anything. Neither pushed anything or reload anything. And it works now... I might have deleted a user by hand tho and it had sub collections and not the others. I saw in the documentation that it might be an issue. Thanks for the help